# I imported images from google as ".gif," and wanted to add a detection collision into my python turtle program. Can anyone assist?

Tags: python, encoding, python-import, collision-detection, python-turtle

```
#This section of the code enables the user to Start the game (Added Function)
def askToPlayGame(game):
     response = input("Want to play SpaceWars? (Y/N)")
     if response == "Y":
        print("The Game Is Activated")
     else:
        # Responses other than "Y" (includes "N")
        print("User Doesn't Want To Play SpaceWars")
        print("Too Bad, May The Force Be With You!")
     return response
GamePartsList = ["1"]
shouldShowEverything = True
for part in GamePartsList:
    answer = (askToPlayGame(part) == "Y") #Is true if response was a yes.
    shouldShowEverything = answer and True # Makes shouldShowEverything stay true only if all responses are True

# List OF Game Characters - (User Input)
print("Choose A SpaceWars Character!: ")
selected_character  = ""
my_charectors = ["kylo-ren", "darth-vader", "luke-skywalker", "obi-wan"]
for character in range(0,len(my_charectors)):
         print(str(character) +". " + my_charectors[character])

chosenCharacter = input("Chosen character: ")
selected_character = my_charectors[int(chosenCharacter)]

#All Imported Turtles
import turtle as trtl
import math
import time
import sys
import winsound
winsound.PlaySound("soundtrack.wav", winsound.SND_ASYNC)

#This Portion Of The Code Aids In Python Errors
print(sys.getrecursionlimit())
sys.setrecursionlimit(2000)
print(sys.getrecursionlimit())

wn = trtl.Screen()
wn.setup(width=1.0, height=1.0)
wn.bgpic("background.gif")

#this Portion Of The Code Adds The 2 SpaceShips
import turtle, os
spaceship = turtle.Turtle()
spaceship.penup()
spaceship.setposition(-650, -120)
spaceship.speed(10000)
wn.addshape(os.path.expanduser("spaceship.gif"))
spaceship.shape(os.path.expanduser("spaceship.gif"))
import turtle, os
spaceship_two = turtle.Turtle()
spaceship_two.penup()
spaceship_two.setposition(-650, 200)
spaceship_two.speed(10000)
wn.addshape(os.path.expanduser("spaceship2.gif"))
spaceship_two.shape(os.path.expanduser("spaceship2.gif"))

#This Portion Of The Code Creates The Charector's Shape And Position 
import turtle, os
wn = turtle.Screen()
playercharacter = turtle.Turtle()
playercharacter.penup()
playercharacter.setposition(600, -85)
wn.addshape(os.path.expanduser(selected_character+".gif"))
playercharacter.shape(os.path.expanduser(selected_character+".gif"))
playercharacter_state = "steady"
time = 0
timeToWait = 0

#This portion of the code creates the timer, adds lasers, and ends the game at Survival Score 250
laser1 = trtl.Turtle()
laser1.penup()
laser1.setposition(-500, -120)
laser1.shape("arrow")
laser1.color("Red")
laser2 = trtl.Turtle()
laser2.penup()
laser2.setposition(-500, 200)
laser2.shape("arrow")
laser2.color("Red")
timer = 0
counter_interval = 550 #1000 = 1 second
timer_up = False
counter =  turtle.Turtle()
counter.color("Dark Red")
counter.hideturtle()
counter.penup()
counter.goto(-775,350)
font_setup = ("Arial", 20, "normal")
def countdown():
  global timer, timer_up, laser1, laser2
  counter.clear()
  counter.write("Survival Score: " + str(timer), font=font_setup)
  timer += 1
  counter.getscreen().ontimer(countdown, counter_interval)
  if laser1.xcor() > 800 and laser2.xcor() > 800:
   laser1.setposition(-500, -120)
   laser2.setposition(-500, 200)
  # Divides time by 50, gets the closest whole number, and multiplies that by 20 / As score goes up by +50, laser speed goes up by +20.
  speedFactor = math.ceil(timer/50) * 20
  laser1.forward(150 + speedFactor) #speed
  laser2.forward(110 + speedFactor) #speed 
countdown()


#This portion of the code enables the playercharacter to jump
def jump_playercharacter():
    global playercharacter_state
    if playercharacter_state == "steady":
        playercharacter_state = "jump"
    playercharacter.penup()
    playercharacter.speed(1)
    x = playercharacter.xcor()
    y = playercharacter.ycor() + 410
    playercharacter.setposition(x, y)
    y = playercharacter.ycor() - 410
    playercharacter.setposition(x, y)

# function for keys commands
  
def RunnerLeft():
    playercharacter.setheading(180)
    playercharacter.forward(15)

def RunnerRight():
    playercharacter.setheading(0)
    playercharacter.forward(15)   

def RunnerMove():
   playercharacter.forward(15)

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.onkeypress(RunnerRight, "D")
wn.onkeypress(RunnerLeft, "A")
wn.onkeypress(RunnerRight, "d")
wn.onkeypress(RunnerLeft, "a")
wn.onkey(jump_playercharacter, "space")

wn.delay(-100)
wn.update()
wn.listen()
wn.mainloop()
```

I adeeded two turtles as spaceships, and with my timer, I made the "arrow" turtle shoot at my other turtle with imported starwars charectors at certiant cords specific to the tip of the spaceship while one goes faster than the other so I could jump over one while dodging the other. How could I define my image length and width for all my four charectors, as well as my "arrow" lasers, and add a collision detection to python turtle?

Comment: This is pretty broad. Can you make an attempt at doing it yourself and ask a specific technical question if you get stuck? There are a few resources for py turtle collision on the site.

Comment: I don't know where to start and am struggling

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/

Comment: a nice bit of code, but difficult to help when the code requires external files. . .   how to ask a good question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask